# Exit File Watcher When a file is created

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a file watcher. And when a file is created the file watcher should stop until it is called again. I have got the following code which is watching and the loop doesn't stop.

```
    public void startwatch()
    {
            string path = "C:\\testwatcher\\";
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

            watcher.Path = path;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
            watcher.Filter = "*.*"; 
            watcher.Created += watcher_Created;
            while (true) ;
    }
    static void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string FileName = ("C:\\testfilescrated\\");
        string text = File.ReadAllText(e.FullPath);
        File.WriteAllText(FileName, text);
    }
```

What i want to do is while loop should end when a file is created.

Comment: Very bad. Why are you busy waiting for a event which may/may not happen? Do it asynchronously.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel how you do it asynchronously

Comment: Remove the while true, let the thread to continue. Then handle the `Created` event of watcher and proceed. I can't provide more specific answer with provided information.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel can you write an example please

Comment: Am afraid, there is not enough information to answer. Answer will depend on what you're trying to do with this. Why you want to wait? What is the code after `startwatch` ? Then I'll be able answer.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i am trying to create a web page when user click on a button it should call some script.That script will create a file which i need to use for further processing. The time is not know it can take hours to produce the file. this is what i am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a busy loop, this will unnecessarily eat CPU. You could use a wait handle, for example using a [`ManualResetEvent`'s `WaitOne()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58195swd(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ManualResetEvent _resetEvent;

public void StartWatch()
{
    // Start watching...

    // Wait until signaled.
    _resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    _resetEvent.WaitOne();
}

void watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle your file...

    // And signal.
    _resetEvent.Set();  
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Had to remove the static word from static void watcher_Created (object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) as it can't access the non static (ManualResetEvent _resetEvent;) memebr.